# How to find children and parents from hierarchy in one SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have table with tree hierarchy:

```
id, path
1, "/1/"
2, "/1/2/"
3, "/1/2/3/"
4, "/1/2/3/4/"
5, "/1/5/"
6, "/1/5/6/"

id - int, path - string.
```

Table doesn't have any reference for parent and depth.

So question, how to get children and parent for any element? Current solution looks like this `SELECT  * FROM table WHERE ((path LIKE '/1/2/' || '%') OR ('/1/2/' LIKE path || '%'));`. It's slow and could be optimized by PostgreSQL indexes(second part of query, first part was optimized by GIN index).

I tried to use `inner join` but it slower then current solution.

Comment: You need to change the design of DB. Add column `parent_id`.

Comment: @i486 we couldn't do it right now. In next release for sure.

Comment: If you would have dots instead of slashes, you cud use ltree datatype, which supports GIST indexes and btree effectively...

Comment: if you create a table that has children linked to parents by foreign key instead of using path strings, you can then use `with recursive` to do all sorts of neat stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you stick with your design you could rewrite it to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE path LIKE '/1/2/' || '%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE '/1/2/' LIKE path || '%';
```

And add index on `path`.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table(path);
```

Comment: What index I should add?

Comment: It's simple `btree` index, it doesn't help when you have `'/1/2/' LIKE path || '%'` or `path LIKE '/1/2/' || '%'` in `WHERE` clause. For `path LIKE '/1/2/' || '%'` we have GIN index.